# Is there a website or a survey collecting all NP-complete problems on graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, np

I wonder whether there is a website or a survey collecting all known NP-complete or NP-hard problems on graph theory?

Comment: "All known problems" is asking a lot...

Comment: By the way, there is a stackexchange for theoretical computer science (:

Comment: I would guess not, because it is fairly straightforward to invent new NP-complete / NP-hard graph theory problems; e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04120

Comment: Somewhat related question at cstheory.SE: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4784/2367

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [section on graph theory](https://www.csc.kth.se/%7Eviggo/wwwcompendium/node8.html) in *A compendium of NP optimization problems* by P. Crescenzi and V. Kann.

Answer (score 13):

A site dedicated to graph classes, including the computational complexity of associated problems, is

https://www.graphclasses.org

Answer (score 8):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems
$$
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
$$

Comment: That both has non-graph theory problems and also doesn't seem to include every NP-complete graph theory problem. So not quite what the question is asking for.

Comment: A plus point is that the wikipedia list is both curated and regularly updated, in contrast to the list by Crescenzi and Kann - which has been discontinued in the 2000s. It's good to have those resources at hand when you're trying to establish NP-hardness of some graph problem. In my own research, I have successfully made use of the original Garey & Johnson 1979 list, which seems to be among the first of that kind.